# aws crontab not working using subprocess

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, amazon-web-services

Crontab is working but not executing aws cli command. I am using python and Subprocess.Popen

```
import subprocess
does not work...
proc = subprocess.Popen("aws rds describe-db-instances > /tmp/testoutput.txt", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

does work...
proc = subprocess.Popen("echo $(date) > /tmp/testoutput.txt", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

same user and same permissions also same permission on aws credentials.
aws rds describe-db-instances works from command line

Comment: What does this print?  print subprocess.Popen("aws rds describe-db-instances > /tmp/testoutput.txt", shell=True)

Comment: it does not print any thing, it appears it is not getting extricated. It seems to be some permissions issues. According to my syslogs script is getting extricated every min.

Comment: What does it write to /tmp/testoutput.txt ?

Comment: its suppose to write the entire json stack return of AWS.

Comment: Are you running `proc.communicate()`? Hm, you must be because one of them works and the other does not... Does `aws rds describe-db-instances` use stderr instead of stdout?

Comment: I am using crontab -e to add my script to the crontab

Comment: let me check stderr opeton

Comment: Ahhh.. You're showing us "similar use of Popen(), but not exactly how you're invoking crontab..." ?  Why not just use subprocess.call(). That fires off the subprocess and waits for it to finish before returning.

Comment: subprocess.call("aws rds describe-db-instances > /tmp/testoutput.txt",shell=True)

Again work from command prompt but not from cron

Comment: error in subprocess 
/bin/sh: 1: aws: not found error found

Comment: so I have to give a full aws CLI's address

Comment: so I have to give a full aws CLI's address, but now the error is
Unable to construct an endpoint for rds in region None

Comment: yes its workin so user must specify the full address of the AWS CLL the full address normally is /usr/local/bin/aws rds describe-db-instances --region 'us-east-1'

Comment: How did you configure the credentials for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add credentials in your env variables or create a confirgratin file. Aws click will automatically locate the credentials